# Native PHP : how to invoke a DELETE of a composite key

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with native PHP (MVC structure) on the backend (with MySQL) and Angular on the frontend.

In my DB, I have a table where its rows are made of two columns that together make a composite key.

My question is how does it work to delete an item from it in the controller?

In the model I have the following method:

```
    public function delete( $nationid, $traitid ) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("
            DELETE FROM traits_by_nation
            WHERE (trait_id = ? AND nation_id = ?)
        ");
        return $query->execute([
            $traitid,
            $nationid
        ]);  
    }
```

And in it's respective controller I have:

```
require("models/traits_by_nation.php");

$model = new TraitToNation();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "DELETE" ) {
    if(
        !empty($traitid) && 
        !empty($nationid)
        ) {
            console.log($traitid);
            console.log($nationid);

        $result = $model->delete($nationid,$traitid);

        if($result) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted");
            echo '{"message":"Deleted item ' .$nationid + '"&"' + $traitid. '"}';
        }
        else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
            echo '{"message":"Bad Request"}';
        }
    }
}
```

I am already getting the $traitid and $nationid in frontend via another method, and then I am calling it in my Angular frontend service like this:

```
removeTraitfromNation(trait_id: number, nation_id: string) {
    let url = this.TraitsToNationDBLink + "/" + trait_id +  "&" + nation_id
    return this.http.delete ( url, this.httpOptions );
  }
```

I know (via console.logs) that I am getting correctly those items (and matching ids in the DB.

But when I run Rester to test it... it just gives me a "200 OK" response, nothing happens. I know it is recognizing the DELETE request (else it would give me a 405 response) and it's not bringing back anything from the console.logs.

So... what am I doing wrong? Is it the way I am calling it in the Rester? ( example: localhost/backend/traitstonation/RC&8)

Any insight would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set `$traitid` and `$nationid`? They need to come from the query parameters.

Comment: _Side note:_ `console.log($traitid);` is not PHP, that's JavaScript. You can't write JavaScript in PHP like that. PHP is also a _server_ side language (gets executed on the server) while JavaScript is a _client_ side language (executed on the client, like the browser)

Comment: You're not looking for a 200 you're looking for a 202. you are also missing a closing in your request method if statement. Go and check your php log files for errors. Which there will be.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you're right, that's from working too much on the frontend. It should be var_dump instead of console.log.

Comment: @Wakka the closing was just a typo (I copied wrongly here) but it is correctly closed on the project.

Comment: @Barmar shouldn't I be getting the $traitid and $nationid from the url? that's where I am losing myself (I think!)

Comment: You need to get them from `$_GET['traitid']` and `$_GET['nationid']`

Comment: @Barmar I am already getting those in my frontend prior to calling the delete. I'll update my main post to explain it better.

Comment: `$_GET` is how PHP code gets a value from the URL query parameters.

Comment: Post the actual URL you're accessing the PHP with and show us how you get those variables from the request and create the variables.